# Prevent GitHub from interpreting #nnnn in commit messages

Tags: github, trac, ticket-system

We’d like to allow contributors to use GitHub pull requests on our git mirror on GitHub to submit code. But we are using trac otherwise for issue management, which means that the `#nnnn` namespace is already taken.

I am worried that by default, GitHub would start linking random commits to unrelated pull requests, just because these happen to mention a trac ticket that happens to have the same number.

Is there a way to prevent GitHub from interpreting these numbers in a repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub support team writes:

> Disabling that linking is not possible currently, and I'm not sure if
>   that feature will be available in the near future. Still, I'll add
>   your request to our feature request wishlist and pass the feedback to
>   the team.
>
> Thanks for the question/suggestion and let us know if there's anything
>   else.